# Flutter: wrong itemBuilder index order in StaggeredGridView

Tags: flutter, staggered-gridview

So, I passed the padding of the StaggeredGridView element manually, checking the index in the itemBuilder method, but there is a wrong index order. Starting from the 3rd index, the order is different, and after some scrolling there will be indices with other order.

[image]

Indexes:

[image]

After some scroll:

[image]

I can't use padding and axis spaces of staggered grid view for avoid leading and trailing white spaces of top horizontal categories list view.
How to solve that a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `flutter_staggered_grid_view` package. Staggered grid view doesn't order items from left to right and then vertically. Within a "row" of items, the one further up than the other will be first in order of indexes.

Check out the [package documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view). There's a pretty self explanatory image there.